# Why did it blow up?

Tags: arduino-nano, pcb-design

I recently designed a PCB to hold an Arduino Nano, IMU and other components. I'm using this platform as the fly computer of a homemade drone. This is one of my first PCB designs and I'm not an expert, so perhaps I'm missing something obvious here.

Now let us get to the problem. I started by testing each component, the Arduino (CPU), CPU + IMU, CPU + HC-05, **CPU + HC-05 + RTX(RC receiver)**. At this last point, the Arduino stopped responding, the RX TX and POW LEDs stay ON all the time. I can't upload new software to it.

I noticed that the ATmega328 was extremely hot! I tried powering the Arduino from the +5V and same result (LEDs stuck ON).

During testing, I had a 3SLiPo battery connected to the PW(top right) of the PCB, and the Arduino was also connected to my PC through the USB port.

Do you see any issues with the PCB design itself?

List of the components tested:

- [Arduino NANO](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B072BMYZ18/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- [HC-05](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01G9KSAF6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- [FlySky receiver](https://uk.banggood.com/Flysky-2_4G-6CH-FS-iA6B-Receiver-PPM-Output-With-iBus-Port-p-978603.html?gmcCountry=GB&currency=GBP&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_bgcs&utm_content=garman&utm_campaign=pla-gbg-rm-all-purchase-pc&ad_id=323612825005&gclid=Cj0KCQjw84XtBRDWARIsAAU1aM1AM1Ph1Cm8yNHLWvU-pMwuvPlnXu8sYHjvopMMNbMzBF3utqVHO5EaAprFEALw_wcB&cur_warehouse=UK)
- R1 1k
- R2 2K
- C1 10uF

[image: PCB]

Thanks.

Comment: how much current does the RTX need for operating?

Comment: @chrisl Something like 40mA

Comment: `Do you see any issues with the PCB design itself?` -- Aside from the too-thin power traces and terrible grounding? No, nothing jumps out at me...

Comment: You say: "3SLiPo battery connected to the PW(top right) of the PCB, and the Arduino was also connected to my PC through the USB port."  I would be suspicious you are driving the power from 2 different sources.  There is a diode in the Nano between the USB's power and 5V Regulator.  But I still would only use one power source at a time.

Comment: @Majenko I didn't even think of making the power traces wider, thats a good idea for future PCBs. Regarding the grounds, how would you improve that?

Comment: Generally speaking, people usually "flood" the ground.

Comment: Yep, @st2000 has it right. A single near-solid ground fill that covers everything is the normal way - then ground connections are just "thermal" connections to that plane.

Comment: @st2000 Yeah not sure why I did that. Also having mixed grounds from the battery and the USB doesn´t sound great.

Comment: Again, generally, all grounds need to be tied together.  I should add that, generally, all grounds should connect at a single point (flooding will probably get you there).  Not looped around the board (which is usually thought of as bad because of ground loops, trace resistance & noise).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm tempted to try this again (without the two power sources) before redesigning the PCB.

Comment: May I ask, why the HC's Tx/Rx are not connected to the arduinos serial? And what's the purpose of R1 and R2?

Comment: The HC-05 is surely connected to SoftwareSerial. And the resistors are a voltage divider, because the HC-05 needs 3.3V logic level at it's RX.

Comment: @SimSon Sure, I do a lot of debugging using the USB port and also I update the code often, so I didn't want to be unplugging the HC05 all the time. As chrisl said, those resistors are used to reduce the voltage into the HC RX (it expects 3.3V not 5).

Comment: For higher currents, a DC-DC converter (or if you really want to save every gram one provided by either of the 4 ESCs) might be a good idea.
I don't see any additional problem with the PCB either, but the code could explain what happened. Maybe you initialized the wrong pin as an output?
One more thing to check: my Nano clones have AMS1117-5.0 as an LDO, but its pinout is different than a non-AMS one. If the manufacturer loaded the other one into the machine for that batch, that could cause trouble (but only if someone used it from VIN). Just look at the trace from VIN to the LDO to be sure.